# Hibernate error when adding hbm tag to hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to understand how it works, so I made a servlet that establishes a connection to a DB with hibernate. Everything works fine until I add an hbm file to the configuration.cfg.xml . I cannot undestand why when I add this the servlet crashes.

My directory is this:

[image]

the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>


                <!-- Database connection settings -->
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/realestate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name='connection.pool_size'>1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name='show_sql'>true</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
         <--without the below line works fine-->
        <mapping resource="Entities/Users.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

the Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `realEstate`.`Users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `RegistrationDate` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Registered` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

the Users class

```
     package Entities;

    public class Users {
        private int user_id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String date;
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private String phone;
        private String email;
        private boolean registered;

        public int getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }
        public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public boolean getRegistered() {
            return registered;
        }
        public void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
            this.registered = registered;
        }

}
```

and the hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Users" table="USERS">
        <id name="user_id" type="int">
            <column name="user_id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Username" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Password" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Name" length="45"/>
        </property>
         <property name="date" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="RegistrationDate" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="surname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Surname" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Phone" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Email" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="registered" type="boolean">
            <column name="Registered" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**I tried adding another hbm file and the problem remains.**

Can you help me? Thx in advance!

Edit: here's the stacktrace
type Exception report

> message Error instantiating servlet class servlets.a
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   servlets.a
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:22)
>     servlets.a.(a.java:35)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType overrides final method
>   getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2479)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:880)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1294)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
>     org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.(BasicTypeRegistry.java:91)
>     org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.(TypeResolver.java:59)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:250)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:302)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.(AnnotationConfiguration.java:168)
>     hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:15)
>     servlets.a.(a.java:35)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.9 logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name should be "Entities.Users" and not "entities.User" in your mapping file. I would rather go with "Users" and specify package like `<hibernate-mapping package="Entities">`
But I highly doubt if this is causing the problem. Can you please provide the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I changed the way you proposed but it doesn't work either. I updated the question with the stacktrace

Comment: @JmRag i believe there is not jar issues.
Which version of Hibernate you are using
If you have both of these `annotation-3.5.6-Final` and `core-3.6.2.Final` try removing annotaion and verify, might be different versions in your code

Comment: @ankur-singhal I did what you suggested but the problem remains